# Inconsistent results with JavaScript fetch API

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I'm creating a simple Weather app using React and I'm using the fetch API to get weather info from OpenWeather, but something strange happens every so often when run the app.

There's a conditional render for the "state" data variable. If the state.name is "Globe", which happens when making a get request to latitude  0 and longitude 0, the icon is displayed. Otherwise, a component that shows information about the weather in a certain location is displayed.

Sometimes the Weather component is rendered, implying the fetch request worked and completed, but other times the Weather component is not being rendered even when more than 15 minutes passes. Which I'm assuming means the fetch call didn't return anything. The code relevant to the problem is down below.

```
const [lat, setLat] = useState(0);
const [long, setLong] = useState(0);
const [data, setData] = useState(weatherDataObj);

const refresh = () => {
  window.location.reload();
};


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        setLat(position.coords.latitude);
        setLong(position.coords.longitude);
      });

      console.log(lat, long);

      await fetch(
        `${api.base}/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          setData(result);
        })
        .then(() => console.log("finished"))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [lat, long]);

  return (
    <>
      <Stack spacing={2}>
        <Button variant="contained" onClick={refresh}>
          Refresh
        </Button>
        {data.name != "Globe" ? (
          <>
            <Weather weatherData={data} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <HourglassBottom></HourglassBottom>
          </>
        )}
      </Stack>
    </>
  );
```

Is my assumption correct? If so, what can I do to resolve this?

I've tried using the fetch call in a different fashion via a try catch statement and replaced the "then" chains with introducing response and result variables, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Don't assume, check your network tab. What are you getting back for the failed requests?

Comment: I'd strongly advise separating the `getCurrentPosition()` from `fetchData`. Run it once in a mount effect hook (empty dependency array)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the API request is made with the updated lat and long values and that the logs reflect these changes, you can use the useEffect dependency array correctly. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async (position) => {
    const lat = position.coords.latitude;
    const long = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log(lat, long);

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${api.base}/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`
      );
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      const result = await response.json();
      setData(result);
      console.log("finished");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
    }
  });
};
fetchData();
```

}, []);

In this updated code, the async/await pattern is used to handle asynchronous operations, and to make sure that the logs reflect the updated lat and long values. Additionally, [lat, long] is removed from the dependency array to avoid unnecessary fetch requests when lat and long change, as this can create an infinite loop. Instead, the API request is made once when the component mounts. Also I suggest to check out these links:

[navigator geolocation getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition)

[useEffect dependency array](https://codedamn.com/news/reactjs/useeffect-dependency)

Comment: I tried your solution and it works. Thanks for the help.